# Existence of equilibrium in games with non-convex best-response correspondence

Tags: game-theory, fixed-point-theorems, nash-equilibrium

Consider a two-player game where player 1 chooses $a\in[0,1]$, player 2 chooses $b\in[0,1]$ and the payoffs are two functions $f,g:[0,1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$ (resp.) which are $C^2$. We focus on player 1 but everything is also true for Player 2 ($f$ and $g$ are very similar).

The sign of the derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. to $a$ is unknown. In particular, it is not known whether $\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}<0$ so it is not clear that the best-response correspondence $b\to argmax f(x,b)$ is convex valued and thus the standard fixed point theorems are not helpful.

However, I do know that $\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial b}<0$, $\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial b^2}>0$ and $\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\partial b}>0$ in the entire domain $[0,1]^2$.

The question is whether it is enough to ensure the existence of equilibrium or, if not, what would be a simple modification that ensures such existence?

For example, from $\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\partial b}>0$ I can deduce that the BR correspondence is increasing, so if $a^*$ is a best response to some $b$, it is not a best response to any other $b$, and the best response to $b'>b$ is higher than $a^*$. This means (along with a similar argument for player 2) that any equilibrium must be at points where the BR correspondence returns a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a special case of the [Tarski fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).

> Let $F: [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]^2$ such that $(a',b') \ge (a,b)$ implies $F(a',b') \ge F(a,b)$.  Then $F$ has a fixed point.

*Note*: In the above, we say $(x',y')\ge (x,y)$ if and only if both $x' \ge x$ and $y' \ge y$.

So in particular, if $F(a,b) = \big(BR_1(b), BR_2(a)\big)$ where both $BR_i(\cdot)$ are nondecreasing functions from $[0,1]\to [0,1]$, then $F$ satisfies the conditions needed and you're guaranteed an equilibrium.

---

More generally, this type of problem is an example of a **supermodular game**.  For some nice notes on these, see [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejdlevin/Econ%20286/Supermodular%20Games.pdf).  The appeal of these kind of results is that you don't need (in general) smoothness or even continuity type conditions on your model primitives.  The order-theoretic property of best-responses being 'weakly increasing' turns out to be enough to get equilibrium (and there's a wealth of useful results about comparative statics, convergence of various processes to equilibrium and so forth).  The classical references are:

- Milgrom & Roberts (1990) *“Rationalizability and Learning in Games with Strategic Complementarities”*
- Milgrom & Shannon (1994) *"Monotone Comparative Statics"*